# Save file in specific folder with Google Drive SDK

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I've been trying to save a plain text file into a specific folder in Google Drive on Android.

So far using the Documentation and [QuickStart Guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android) on Google Drive I have been able to do a few things that are going in the right direction, first I was able to create a plain text file:

```
  File body = new File();
  body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
  body.setMimeType("text/plain");
  File file = service.files().insert(body, textContent).execute();
```

I have been able to create a new folder in the base directory of Google Drive with:

```
  File body = new File();
  body.setTitle("Air Note");
  body.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");
  File file = service.files().insert(body).execute();
```

I have also been able to list all of the folders in the user's Google Drive account with:

```
      List<File> files = service.files().list().setQ("mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'").execute().getItems();
      for (File f : files) {
          System.out.println(f.getTitle() + ", " + f.getMimeType());
      }
```

However I am a bit stuck on how to save a text file into a folder within Google Drive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the parent parameter to put a file in a folder using insert. More details at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

Something like this

```
File body = new File();  
body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
body.setMimeType("text/plain");
body.setParents(Arrays.asList(new File.ParentReference().setId(parentId));  
File file = service.files().insert(body, textContent).execute();
```

Comment: How do you get a hold of the `parentId`?

Comment: If you know where ur going store, its pretty much straight forward

Comment: service is which type of object?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to INSERT a file in specific folder in Google Drive then follow these steps. Lets assume that we have retrieved all folder from the Drive and now i will INSERT an empty file in the first folder from the list, So

```
         //Getting Folders from the DRIVE
List<File> files = mService.files().list().setQ("mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'").execute().getItems();

   File f  =files.get(1)//getting first file from the folder list
    body.setTitle("MyEmptyFile");
    body.setMimeType("image/jpeg");
    body.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(f.getId())));
    com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = mService.files().insert(body).execute();
```

Now this will create an empty file in the Folder which are at the top in the retrieve file list.

Answer (score 0):

Step1 : Create a folder

```
File body1 = new File();
body1.setTitle("cloudbox");
body1.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");
File file1 = service.files().insert(body1).execute();
```

Step2 : Insert your file

```
File body2 = new File();  
body2.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
body2.setMimeType("text/plain");
body2.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(file1.getId())));  
File file2 = service.files().insert(body2, mediaContent).execute();
```