# Save file in specific folder with Google Drive SDK Java

Tags: java, google-drive-api

Since I was not allowed to ask in the relevant thread [Save file in specific folder with Google Drive SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422661/save-file-in-specific-folder-with-google-drive-sdk/21357711#21357711)

```
File body = new File();  
body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
body.setMimeType("text/plain");
body.setParents(Arrays.asList(new File.ParentReference().setId(parentId));  
File file = service.files().insert(body, textContent).execute();
```

The File. ".ParentReference()" is giving me a problem what am I missing?

My current code which will not load into folder XXX

```
      HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setFromTokenResponse(response);

//      Create a new authorized API client
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();

        ParentReference newParent = new ParentReference();
        newParent.setId("XXX");

//      Insert a file  
        File body = new File();
        body.setTitle(fileID);
        body.setDescription(fileID);
        body.setMimeType("text/plain");
        body.setParents(Arrays.asList(newParent));

        List<File> files = service.files().list().setQ("mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'").execute().getItems();
        for (File f : files) {
            System.out.println(f.getTitle() + ", " + f.getMimeType());
        }

        java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(fileID);
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileContent);

        File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
        System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
```

Answer (score 1):

Adds a parent folder for a file.

```
  private static ParentReference insertFileIntoFolder(Drive service, String folderId,
      String fileId) {
    ParentReference newParent = new ParentReference();
    newParent.setId(folderId);
    try {
      return service.parents().insert(fileId, newParent).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

See

- [**Parents: insert**](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents/insert#examples)

Comment: Yeah still having problems.I've seen this.